# Turning off debug_kit within controller action, Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am currently working on an export function in cakephp app and im doing a query that is getting around 10,000 rows each export which cake can handle but debug_kit seems to be using lot of memory and putting me over 128mb of memory used.

I have tried tried writing this in the top of the function but debugkit is still getting involved and using large amounts of memory.

```
Configure::write('debug',0);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HyperCas is correct in suggesting the beforeFilter() callback as an appropriate solution.

The code could look something like this in the controller where the action (ie, export) resides:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    // filter actions which should not output debug messages
    if(in_array($this->action, array('export'))) {
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
    }
}
```

You would adjust `array('export')` to include all the actions you want to prevent debug.

Answer (score 9):

Just to improve [Benjamin Pearson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009677/turning-off-debug-kit-within-controller-action-cakephp/2013416#2013416). Unload the component instead of turning debugging off.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if(in_array($this->action, array('export'))) {
        $this->Components->unload('DebugKit.Toolbar');
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not work in cakephp1.3 because i don't think cakephp1.3 allows to load and and upload the components on the fly.This functionality was added to cakephp 2.x

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Components.html

@Hamid  do you know how to do this in caakephp1.3 ?

Comment: @nedstark I couldn't find a similar method in 1.3. Chances are you're right. Did you try Benjamin's solution?

Comment: I prefer this answer to completely disabling debugging. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Configure::write('debug',0);
```

in /app/config/core.php

Or use it in the beforeFilter() callback on the controller. That would stop the debugging for the entire controller if you don't check manually for the current action (in **$this->params['action']**).

If your model has multiple associations you should take a look at the containable behavior

http://book.cakephp.org/view/51/Controller-Attributes

Comment: That will stop it of course but i want to stop on a per action basis as i still would like to use it in other locations.

Comment: you could try the beforeFilter() callback

Answer (score 0):

you can also switch the debug level in the config.php to 0. this will disable the debug kit automaticaly + your application will use even less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Disable `debug_kit` on the fly

```
class AppController extends Controller {
     public function beforeFilter() {
         Configure::write('debug', 0);
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in cakephp3  open **bootstrap.php** file in **config** folder
comments or remove the DebugKit loading

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
   // Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
```

thats all .. it will unload the DebugKit from your application

Comment: The question was about doing this for a specific action, not the whole application.